# The Appropriate CMS and extensions for a dynamic tagging with social features

Tags: c#, drupal, content-management-system, social-networking

I am seeking to create a dynamic tagging site with social features.  The closest comparative is GDGT.com, which is a social network around gadgets.  My site will be organized around a different topic altogether, but I like how GDGT does their dynamic tagging, discussions, and wiki.  I also love Stack Overflow's dynamic tagging and badges.

The framers of this concept are not deeply technical.  In other words, we know enough PHP and C# to be dangerous, but will have to hire out the complicated stuff.

So, the main question is, which CMS is the most out-of-the-gate capable for this type of site.  A combination CMS and CMS Extensions would be fine, too.  We have evaluated ELGG, and find that the developer base is too small.  We have also evaluated Wordpress, and find it's heritage as a blogging-only tool limiting.  Drupal is still a contender, but looking for guidance on the appropriate extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal can handle the requirements you describe. The more specific your requirements are though, the more work you'll have to do to customize Drupal. In particular, I suspect the wiki functionality would to be the most difficult to configure, if your requirements are especially specific. Configuring a wiki in Drupal [can be a bit difficult](http://drupal.org/node/356583). However, there is now a [wiki installation profile](http://drupal.org/project/drupal_wiki) that could save you some time.

Comment: I agree, Drupal is great for community websites and has powerful taxonomy features.